# A tool to trace field and object references

Tags: schema-builder

We want to get rid of an app that has a bunch of objects which are referenced by other cusotm objects in our org. There are tons of references to these objects such as lookup fields in other objects, Apex, Flows etc.

Is there a tool which could somehow show all of the references to an object and its fields ? I know that's not realistic but I just wanted to see if anybody could get me anything which could be helpful.

I don't think Schema Builder will be of much help in this case because I'm talking about at least 30 other objects which reference these objects - so building anything out on Schema Builder would not be very productive. Ideally, I would have something similar to Field Trip which could product a report showing all the references for every field of the objects.

Thank you for any input you can give.

Comment: I think you'll be interested in [Daniel Ballinger's Dreamforce talk](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2771/dreamforce-2018-sfse-speakers).

Comment: oh wow, that is really interesting. I started watching it just now. I wish I had noticed it when I was at Dreamforce. Thank you very much !

Comment: Are not these features enough: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_fields_where.htm and 

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.214.0.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatacomponentdependency.htm

Comment: @Ayub - I actually don't see the "Where is this used ?" button in the field details. It listed as "Pilot" on that page. Do I need to request it ? I just put in a case in SF help desk.  I'm not really sure how to use the MetadataComponentDependency.

Comment: There are two links...one is button 'Where this is used' will be released in winter 19. One is tolling api object "MetadatacompoenentDependency" that is beta and you need to ask Salesforce to enable it in your org.